# What was Steve Rogers's phone number?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, we see a few times that Tony Stark has Steve Rogers's/Captain America’s phone number saved to his cell phone.

Steve’s number is shown on-screen two times: Once when Tony tries to call, and once when Bruce Banner goes to call.

What was Steve Rogers's phone number?

Answer (score 59):

The phone number was/is:

> 678-136-7092

This is unusual [since most films and TV shows famously use “555” numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_(telephone_number)#Fictional_usage). But note how the middle three numbers begins with a “1”; North American phone exchanges cannot begin with a “1” since that is used to indicate the next three digits that follow it is an area code [as this Reddit thread explains](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/34er1c/eli5_why_cant_phone_numbers_start_with_a_1/).

That said, [calling it up won’t reveal anything fun as this article points out](https://www.elitedaily.com/p/captain-americas-phone-number-was-revealed-heres-what-happens-if-you-call-it-8934663):

> When I called the number, I kind of assumed that I might hear a fun little recorded message from Marvel — maybe a jokey away message that the studio had Chris Evans record in character as an Easter egg for fans or something like that — but there was no such luck. Instead, the number is disconnected, and all fans will hear is a recording telling you that the number you have dialed is incorrect. Although Cap's number leads to a dead end, there is still one small Easter egg within the digits — **the area code 678 locates the number in Atlanta, which is a nod to where the movie was filmed and produced, in Georgia.**

And I just called the number and the message you get is:

> “The number or code you have dialed is incorrect. Please check the number or code and try again. El número o código que ha marcado no es correcto. Por favor, compruebe el número o código y vuelva a intentarlo. Message 7. Switch 227.”

Comment: The exchange beginning with a "1" is fictitious by default, as such exchanges are not yet allowed in North America. So, it will get the given message anyway. However, is it possible that there is some other Easter Egg in the number using cipher techniques? Or in relation to something else in the movie, or its cast?

Comment: The phone number may not have any significance. The UK's communications regulator Ofcom [reserves certain telephone ranges or film & fiction](https://www.ofcom.org.uk/phones-telecoms-and-internet/information-for-industry/numbering/numbers-for-drama) which will never be allocated to anyone. (Expand the "notes" section to see those number ranges.) It's possible there's a similar reserved range of numbers for Georgia, and this just happens to be one of them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77177/discussion-on-answer-by-jakegould-what-was-steve-rogerss-phone-number).

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver 1 is the US country code.  It's not 'unsupported' by America.

Comment: @JordanStefanelli The Country Code is the _first_ part of a phone number, when used. The "exchange" is the first three digits in a 7-digit number for US phone numbers. In the exchange for US phone numbers anything in the 000-199 range is _not_ supported. They are currently reserved for future expansion if needed. The Country Code and the exchange are totally different parts of a the number and a 1 being supported in one does not mean it is supported in another part of the number plan.

Answer (score 36):

## 678-136-7092 is Steve's number. But note the "1".

In 1981, Tommy Tutone's song [867-5309](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/867-5309/Jenny) hit the charts. This was at a time when dialing 7 digits worked in every area code. This caused a lot of problems for the numerous unfortunates who did have that number in their area code.  Since then, Hollywood (and music) take [PII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information) **seriously**.

The middle triplet of numbers is called the "Exchange" or "Prefix" and often map to a particular town.  Exchanges starting with 0 or 1 are currently not allowed.* This makes the number even *less real* than the 555-xxxx numbers Hollywood usually uses, since the "555" block is reserved for phone company services (e.g. 555-1212 was the old number for directory assistance before 411) and it's even [possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_telephone_number) for a company to get a 555 number.

So the "1" in the first digit of the exchange field makes this number unroutable, equivalent to an IP address of **241**.211.108.136 (which you'd have to be an IPv4 geek to see the problem with) or www.example.**fed**.

---

* because "1" means an area code follows (1-800-555-1000) and "0" is reserved for operators, international calls and the like (011-44-20-1234-5678).

Comment: @JakeGould This DOES answer the question and frames it in an intelligent context.

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments between you and @JakeGould. Both of you need to keep it civil.

Comment: @Harper - I am grateful for this answer because it expanded on the first comment left in the accepted answer. I was unsure what the "1" and "exchange" meant. This cleared it right up for me. Thank you

Comment: ".fed" may at some point be a real TLD. A slightly more accurate (but pedantic, i know) DNS example would be "www.coastguard.invalid" - [.invalid is reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39286127/860453) and will not be resolveable.

Comment: Can you add the information from Jake's answer about 678 being the area code for Atlanta?